# Find $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \int\limits_{2^t}^{3^t} \frac{x}{\ln x} dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I have the following limit to find:

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \int _{2^t} ^ {3^t} \dfrac{x}{\ln x} dx$$

This wouldn't be a problem if instead of the given fraction, we would have $\dfrac{\ln x}{x}$ since then I could a substitution like $t = \ln x$, but it looks like that doesn't work here.

Most of the limit-integrals that I worked with were solved with the Squeeze Theorem, but I don't see any boundaries that I could use here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\int_{e^{t\log 2}}^{e^{t\log 3}}\frac{x}{\log x}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto e^z}{=} \int_{t\log 2}^{t\log 3}\frac{e^{2z}}{z}\,dz\stackrel{z\mapsto t u}{=}\int_{\log 2}^{\log 3}\frac{e^{2tu}}{u}\,du$$
When $t\mapsto 0$, by the dominated convergence theorem the RHS goes to
$$ \int_{\log 2}^{\log 3}\frac{du}{u}=\color{red}{\log\log 3-\log \log 2}.$$

Comment: How do you get these ideas? How do you know that you need to do that weird substitution of $x = e^z$. I would've never had that idea. Is it just experience with these kinds of problems or are you looking after something in particular?

Answer (score 2):

Let's put $x=u^t$ so that the integral reduces to $$\int_{2}^{3}\frac{u^{2t-1}}{\log u} \, du$$ As $t\to 0$ we can switch limits and integral (because integrand is continuous as a function of two variables) and get the result as $$\int_{2}^{3}\frac{du}{u\log u} =\log\log 3 - \log\log 2$$

Answer (score 1):

For small $t$,
we have
$a^t 
=e^{t\ln(a)}
\approx 1+t\ln(a)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
 \int _{2^t} ^ {3^t} \dfrac{x}{\ln x} dx
&\approx  \int _{1+t\ln(2)} ^ {1+t\ln(3)} \dfrac{x}{\ln x} dx\\
&=  \int _{t\ln(2)} ^ {t\ln(3)} \dfrac{x+1}{\ln (1+x)} dx\\
&\approx  \int _{t\ln(2)} ^ {t\ln(3)} \dfrac{x+1}{x} dx\\
&=  \int _{t\ln(2)} ^ {t\ln(3)} (1+\dfrac1{x})dx\\
&= (1+\ln(x))_{t\ln(2)} ^ {t\ln(3)}\\
&= (t\ln(3)-t\ln(2))+(\ln(t\ln(3))-\ln(t\ln(2)))\\
&= (t\ln(3)-t\ln(2))+(\ln(t)+\ln(\ln(3))-\ln(t)-\ln(\ln(2)))\\
&= (t\ln(3)-t\ln(2))+(\ln(\ln(3))-\ln(\ln(2)))\\
&= t\ln(3/2)+(\ln(\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)})\\
&\to\ln(\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)})\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: If you don't mind, what is that approximation called? Where is it from? I've never seen it before.

Comment: It's just the Taylor series expansion for $e^x$ (centered around 0), where we only include the first two terms.

Comment: $a^t = e^{t \ln(a)} \approx 1+t\ln(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to 0}\int_{2^{\large t}}^ {3^{\large t}}{x \over \ln\pars{x}}\,dx
& =\lim_{t \to 0}\int_{2^{\large t}}^ {3^{\large t}}{dx \over x - 1} =
\lim_{t \to 0}\ln\pars{3^{t} - 1 \over 2^{t} - 1} =
\ln\pars{\lim_{t \to 0}{3^{t} - 1 \over 2^{t} - 1}}
\\[3mm] & =
\ln\pars{\lim_{t \to 0}{3^{t}\ln\pars{3} \over 2^{t}\ln\pars{2}}} =
\bbox[15px,#ffc,border:1px groove navy]
{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{3} \over \ln\pars{2}}}\ \approx\
0.4606
\end{align}

Comment: How did you replace the Integrand with $1/(x-1)$? This needs some justification.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh $\displaystyle {x \over \ln\left(x\right)} \stackrel{\mathrm{as}\ x\ \to\ 1}{\sim} {1 \over x - 1}$